# Change Laravel's DB connection for every Models on the fly dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

Is there a way to change Laravel DB connection, say, through API call, and the data returned before and after that API call will be different for every Models?

The rough concept is:

I have 2 DBs, say **first_database** and **second_database**, a connection called **mysql**, and an API to change the connection's database. Everytime that API gets called, **mysql** connection's database will be changed based on the given parameter. After that, when I get the Models' data, it will be different since it has different database.

Is there a way to do that as efficient as possible? I've looked into:

`DB::connection('...')->select('...')`
,

`config()->set('database.connection', 'second_mysql')` (I tried using different connections)

and `$models = new Model(); $models->setConnection('second_mysql');`.

Both  `DB::connection('...')->select('...')` and `$models = new Model(); $models->setConnection('second_mysql');` is not very efficient in my opinion because I have a lot of models/tables and I don't want to change each of their connection, so these two will be my last resort. What I tried is `config()->set('database.connection', 'second_mysql')` and it works, but also not. It works because when I run this code:

```
config()->set('database.connection', 'second_mysql');
dd(Item::all());
```

(I have **items** table, for the **first_database** it has 3 records and 0 records for **second_database**)
It returned null(this works). But when I run the `config()->...` part and get all **items** as 2 different APIs, get all **items** API returned 3 records from **first_database**(this doesn't work).

Is there anything wrong with that approach? Or do I need other approach to do so?

I will leave my not working code just in case:

- [API method for changing connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY6aG.jpg) (the dump returned **second_mysql** when I passed 1)
- [API method to get all **items**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94wvU.jpg) (the dump returned **mysql** even after I called the API above)

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/dynamic-db-connection-for-model

Comment: This also doesn't get what I want because when I changed the connection, I have to change every Models that I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can define database connection in Eloquent itself

```
protected $connection = "your database connection name";
```

[Laravel Eloquent Database Connections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#database-connections)

In your way you are creating one more connection instead setting connection to default

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')
```

You are required to set value of `default` on the fly. So it should be

```
config()->set('database.default', 'second_mysql');
```

Comment: I tried this one too, but it doesn't really get what I want which is changing the connection on the fly. I tried changing the Models' connection using the first API, but still doesn't work when calling get all items API.